# WatchService freezes JavaFX GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, freeze, watchservice

I've got a JavaFX application which has to trigger whenever a file is renamed. I'm new to WatchService, I've done the demo's and it works.

Though, the demo's are simple applications with 1 class. Now I want to implement it in my own application, making a seperate class to take care of the WatchService.

The Main class:

```
public class KochFractalDraw extends Application {
     @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

                          //..define GUI etc..

            watchdirectory = new WatchDirectory();
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        watchdirectory.Register();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(JSF31KochFractalFX.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            });
    }
```

With WatchDirectory:

```
public class WatchDirectory {

    WatchService watchService;
    Path path;
    WatchKey key;

    public WatchDirectory() throws IOException {

        this.watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
        path = Paths.get("D:\\Test");
        path.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);
    }

    public void Register() throws InterruptedException {
        for (;;) {

            this.key = watchService.take();
            for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
                WatchEvent.Kind kind = event.kind();
                switch (kind.name()) {
                    case "ENTRY_CREATE":
                        System.out.println("Create triggered!");
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Wrong event called.");
                        break;
                }

                boolean valid = key.reset();

                if (!valid) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that it works, but my GUI freezes immediately. Hence why I've put the watchdirectory.Register(); in a RunLater, hoping it wouldn't affect the main JavaFX application thread.

(I know it works because whenever I create/rename a file in "D:\Test" the output will keep responding "Create triggered!")

Comment: well i am not quite sure about the runlater but from my own experience if you want heavy stuff to be called from a frame then make a call to a runnable and when the runnable finished it should call the Platform.RunLater runnable which is a UI handler mostly

Comment: `Platform.runLater(...)` schedules something to run on the FX Application Thread, which is exactly the opposite of what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the tip James_D

I've made WatchDirectory a Runnable.
In my main class I run it with

```
new Thread(watchdirectory).start();
```

I was near this solution before, but then I used .run(); , which froze the GUI again. Did not realize the difference between .start(); and .run();

Never again!

Answer (score 0):

Platform.runLater() is intended to **at some point**  give FX application process execution to run some other small program that runs and **exists** and execution returns the back to FX application.

If you have infinite loop inside that process, like how Watch Service is used, the execution never returns from it and naturally FX app freezes.

You ABSOLUTELY CAN NOT DO the :

```
 while(true) {
    key = watchService.take();  
    ...
 }
```

polling loop when using Platform.runLater().

Instead you have to replace the `while(true)` with some FX component like TimeLine which triggers event every second. And forget Runnable and `Platform.runLater()`, I think for it to work you need the do the polling loop inside FX.

So far I have not figured out how to do this.